# ASP.NET MVC View Align Text Boxes

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I like to align my text boxes so that the text boxes are one right below the other.

I have the following code:

```
     <div style="text-align: left; width: 1000px"> 
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Information</legend>
       @Html.Label("Collector")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Collector)
       <br />
       <br />
        @Html.Label("Email")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)    
 </fieldset>  
 </div>
```

I know using tables is not the way to go. What other means are there to make sure that the text box fields are aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about it.  You could do something along the lines of:

```
<div style="text-align: left; width: 1000px"> 
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Information</legend>
       <div class="form-element-row">           
       @Html.Label("Collector")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Collector)
       </div>
       <div class="form-element-row">
       @Html.Label("Email")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) 
       </div>   
       </fieldset>  
</div>
```

In your CSS file or header, then you can define the alignment of form-element-row (so that each form-element-row div falls beneath the previous). You can define the label (the tag generated by Html.Label) and input (the tag generated by TextBoxFor) margin's and width's such that they are usually aligned:

```
.form-element-row
{
    /* alignment here */
}

.form-element-row label
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:125px;
}

.form-element-row input
{
    width:350px;
}
```

[See this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdrew/E3b7e/1/). I modified the code slightly - I added a class at the parent level div so you don't have to add a class to each child div.

Comment: Hi Drew, can you fill in what sample values should for for the .css. I am still not getting the right results.

Comment: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdrew/E3b7e/) - This is pretty basic CSS

Comment: Here's an alternate solution that only defines one class at the top level. It saves you from having to add a class to each div on the page. [jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdrew/E3b7e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use bootstrap ,pure CSS, foundation etc. these will help with getting a consistent feel for things like forms etc.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

You can customise these frameworks to only include the elements you want but I generally just include the lot.